# Converting Expo Classic's Release Channel to EAS

Tags: react-native, expo, eas

I have converted our old mobile app to the latest version of expo. Seeing that a lot of things had been deprecated including `expo publish`, I'm now integrating the `eas build` to my workflow

In my code before, I have been using `Updates.releaseChannel` before for my env specific config. See code below:

```
export function getEnvConst() {
  if (Updates.releaseChannel.startsWith("prod")) {
    return { apiUrl: "https://prodUrl.com/" };
  } else if (Updates.releaseChannel.startsWith("staging")) {
    return { apiUrl: "https://stagingUrl.com/" };
  } else if (Updates.releaseChannel.startsWith("uat")) {
    return { apiUrl: "https://uatUrl.com/" };
  } else {
    return { apiUrl: "https://devUrl.com/" };
  }
}
```

and I get to select which channel via the following commands:

```
expo publish --release-channel prod
expo publish --release-channel uat
expo publish --release-channel staging
```

This setup allows me to switch `ApiUrl` base on releaseChannel and at the same time, during development (`npm start`) the `else` statement kicks in to run using dev url (since no release channel)

I can't seem to replicate this setup using `eas build`. What I've tried is to add `eas.json` and added a bunch of profile and bunch of env. These env doesn't seem to be accessible to the javascript code as well?

What I tried:

1. Add profile and used `channel`. Literally used the same `getEnvConst` function above and replaced `releaseChannel` with `channel`. The `channel` doesn't seem to be working. I use the following command for publishing `eas build -p android --profile staging` The `eas.json` contains the following:

```
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 3.8.1"
  },
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal",
      "ios": {
        "resourceClass": "m-medium"
      },
      "channel": "dev",
    },
    "staging": {
      "android": {
        "buildType": "apk"
      },
      "ios": {
        "resourceClass": "m-medium"
      },
      "channel": "staging",
    },
    "uat": {
      "distribution": "internal",
      "ios": {
        "resourceClass": "m-medium"
      },
      "channel": "uat",
    },
    "production": {
      "ios": {
        "resourceClass": "m-medium"
      },
      "channel": "production",
    }
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {}
  },
}
```

2. Tried adding `env` in `eas.json`. But this `export const apiUrl = process.env.API_URL` doesn't seem to get the values via `npm start`. Haven't tested it in `eas build` because it takes a lot of time to test...

```
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 3.8.1"
  },
  //Remove other sections for brevity
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal",
      "ios": {
        "resourceClass": "m-medium"
      },
      "channel": "dev",
      "env": {
        "API_URL": "http://devUrl.com/"
      }
    },
    "production": {
      "ios": {
        "resourceClass": "m-medium"
      },
      "channel": "production",
      "env": {
        "API_URL": "https://prodUrl.com/"
      }
    }
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {}
  },
  "development": {
    "client": "local"
  },
  "env": {
    "development": {
      "API_URL": "https://devUrl.com/"
    }
  }
}
```

Honestly I'm just confused with all of this and it's taking me a lot of time than I want to admit, even after reading the documentation. It seems I'm missing the fundamentals of expo that the document assumes I'm aware of so what it says doesn't connect to me.

Comment: I am on the same issue. After playing around for hours, I noticed that my build didn't fetch any profile while I placed a build. That'sthe reason I got an empty string for the Updates.channel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to proceed with that I wanted to happen.

This [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73723359/4724492) answer was the one that solved my problem. It said that I need to add a `branch` first then link my `channel` to it using this command:

```
eas update --branch staging
eas channel:edit staging --branch staging
```

What tripped me before was whenever I run `eas build -p android --profile staging` it doesn't say any warning or error and just completes successfully. This gives me a false idea that my profile's `channel` should take effect. After creating the `branch` and linking my channel to it, the `Updates.channel` now contains the channel in the `eas.json`.

**However**, whenever I run `eas update --channel staging --platform android`, the `Updates.channel` is still null. I just ended up commenting/uncommenting the return of the `else` when I do `eas update` which works for now.

It seems there's not a direct replacement to `expo publish` and `releaseChannel` the way it used before.

My `eas.json` is still similar from before:

```
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 3.8.1"
  },
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal",
      "ios": {
        "resourceClass": "m-medium"
      },
      "channel": "dev"
    },
    "staging": {
      "distribution": "internal",
      "ios": {
        "resourceClass": "m-medium"
      },
      "channel": "staging"
    },
    "uat": {
      "distribution": "internal",
      "ios": {
        "resourceClass": "m-medium"
      },
      "channel": "uat"
    },
    "production": {
      "ios": {
        "resourceClass": "m-medium"
      },
      "channel": "production"
    }
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {}
  }
}
```